# connecting time is more in magento e commerce website

Tags: php, mysql, apache, magento

We are running a Magento website on a dedicated VPS server with 12GB of RAM. The load time of the website is very slow. I have checked GT metrix for the same. Any suggestion to improve the load time. In GT metrix it was showing 10 seconds to load website.

[image]

Comment: This question does not belong here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

For magento, loading problems are most of the time due to bad cache management

Comment: hi nicolas  ve are using memcahe as well as mod page speed in servers